# Protractor tests failing after ugrading to angular5

Tags: protractor, angular5

We have recently upgraded to angular 5. Since then my protractor tests started failing with reason " Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.".

All these tests were working fine before.

Protractor version : 5.2.0
karma version: 1.7.0

Highly appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Jasmine timeout, see the [Protractor guidance on Jasmine timeouts](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#timeouts-from-jasmine):

> **Timeouts from Jasmine**
>
> **Spec Timeout**
>
> If a spec (an 'it' block) takes
>   longer than the Jasmine timeout for any reason, it will fail.
>
> Looks like: a failure in your test results - timeout: timed out after
>   30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
>
> Default timeout: 30 seconds
>
> How to change: To change for all specs, add jasmineNodeOpts:
>   {defaultTimeoutInterval: timeout_in_millis} to your Protractor
>   configuration file. To change for one individual spec, pass a third
>   parameter to it: it(description, testFn, timeout_in_millis).

Try to debug your test, instructions [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging). Following any change, including an upgrade, it's possible your test may be broken; resulting in it hanging beyond the duration of the default Jasmine timeout.
A lazy option would be to increase your Jasmine timeout excessively, to see if your test fails with a different exception.

Comment: Thank you very much. Intrestingly , the issue is not with the timeout or angular 5 upgrade. Infact the tests are working fine on the branch when i downgraded my chrome version to 63.